# How to avoid reloading an image from Glide in modern MVVM/MVI with LiveData/Flow

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

In modern MVVM/MVI architecture, a View is notified of data changes via a state passed using LiveData/Flow observables. On a change of any attribute included in the state, rendering of the whole visual structure is triggered. My problem is that on each such render call I have to do something like this:

```
GlideApp.with(this).load(state.freebieImageUrl).into(binding.freebieImage)
```

which reloads the cached bitmap to the ImageView. It doesn't take long, but is nevertheless completely unnecessary since the image didn't change. I would like to avoid reloading the bitmap if the source image URL is the same. Obviously I can store my image URL in a view tag, but is there a simpler way to achieve this without additional development effort?